# Mass RSU grants vesting -- should I worry about the stock price?

Tags: stocks, brokerage, employee-stock-options

My company was acquired almost a year ago.  In the acquisition, most employees received RSU grants which vested on a 1 year cliff.

These RSUs are managed through Etrade.  My options for tax purposes are "Withhold shares", "Sell to cover", "Cash Transfer" and "Same day sale".

My concern is this -- some back-of-the-envelope math says that, assuming most employees do a same-day-sale (there is no good tax reason not to), the total volume of shares being sold on the acquisition anniversary will be 1-2x the average daily trading volume of the stock.

Should I be concerned that the large number of shares being released on that day will drop the share price (at least temporarily) enough to hurt the price my grant will fetch?  I don't know what kind of protections Etrade has against the market being too shallow to sell shares at a reasonable price.

I could do a "Cash Transfer" if absolutely necessary, but it would be difficult to get enough liquid cash transferred in time for this option.

Comment: what companies?

Comment: "assuming most employees do a same-day-sale" why is this valid? And even so, what percent of the float does this represent?

Comment: (1) the default option is same-day-sale (2) I don't have any exact numbers, but ballpark math says .1% - .2%

Comment: I'd rather not specify companies if not necessary.